# Unload all qt dlls

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I have a dll containing a Qt GUI, launched by a "server" app, which continue after the GUI is killed (unloaded).

All works fine, but if I restart the GUI, all crashed. If I just run once and list loaded dlls, Qt5Core, Qt5Gui and qwindows.dll is never unloaded.

I think that I need to unload them (my dll create a QApplication in dedicated thread, properly destroyed)

I'm using msvc2010 compiler on windows 7, and no logs ("general protection fault" is not a log for me).

Is there any solution to unload all qt dll (Qtcore, QtGui, qwindows) ? (Without calling explicitly "FreeLibrary" function)

Comment: How do you want to unload a .dll without calling a FreeLibrary?

Comment: Qt dlls (Core, etc) aren't loaded explicitly, I just load (and free) my own dll.

Comment: So, if you want to unload Qt with `FreeLibrary` you need to load it with `LoadLibrary`. Read about delay loading of DLL's.

Comment: This way is possible, but ugly :/ Thanks for help =)

Comment: Why it is ugly? it's a default way, if you need custom management of DLL lifetime

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. The crash is not caused by the Qt DLL's which are still loaded. It might be the fact that you try to create a second QApplication object, though. If you want to shut down your GUI, discard all QWindow's, but not QApplication.

Comment: I tried that. But it cannot work because my dll is launch by an intermediate application which is killed (but not every time properly, this is the real problem, solved today at 16 p.m). And, I can't modify the "server" app. Now it's working

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a support ticket with the Qt Company about the same problem and received a disappointing response. There was a conscious design decision to have the Qt plugins remain loaded until the application terminates. As a result, many Qt-based plugins designed for non-Qt host applications will have to resort to brittle work-arounds to ensure proper operation.

When you are unloading the various Qt DLLs, the unloading order is rather important since many of the DLLs depend on each other. Here is the exact response that I received from the Qt support engineer:

> The plugins are deliberately not unloaded until the application
>   terminates as there were problems in the past with unloading the
>   plugins and therefore it was agreed that they should stay loaded for
>   the lifetime of the application. You should unload the plugins first
>   before unloading your own dll. The plugins can be unloaded in any
>   order you want as they do not depend on each other, the main platform
>   one - qwindows.dll - would be the main one which is handling the
>   events and so on. So as long as the QApplication is no longer running
>   an event loop then you should be able to safely unload this. As long
>   as you unload the plugins before the Qt dlls then any clean up that
>   the plugins do will be done with the still loaded Qt dlls and thus
>   should not cause a crash then.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! My (hypothetic) solution will create an independent process, command it with pipe or other way and kill the 'client' process. It's ugly (, real-time forbids ?) and will create security issues but I don't find any other solution...

Answer (score 0):

Solved using GetModuleHandle("dllname"), I get the handle and can use freelibrary. Now works fine =) (but not really "dynamic"... Qt use different names on debug and release, and if another dll is "floating", I need to modify code)

Thanks for help !

Comment: Would you post the order of the DLLs you've unloaded?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain correctly : for the PoC I just get all loaded dll, look for "Qt5" in name and try to call "freelibrary" in while loop for each module (with max of 10 loop). This (ugly) method works for 2 or 3 discharge and reload, but the OS will not free correctly after that (and crash). This is not "really" solved for deployment... :/